# How to achieve resolving of the same hostname to different IP addresses based on location

Tags: ip

I have personal webserver with ownCloud installed. **This webserver has no public IP address** because my internet connection does not offer it.
I ordered virtual linux webserver with a public IP address and I use it just for port forwarding via SSH to allow my ownCloud server be accessible from the internet. Everything works fine and I am accessing the ownCloud via a hostname - example: "mytunneledowncloud.com".

But as I have limited high speed data on my internet connection, **I would like to save some data by synchronizing ownCloud via LAN private IP address when I am at home and not via ssh tunneled public ip address of my virtual server.** 
I am thinking whether this is even possible. I would need to resolve **"mytunneledowncloud.com"** as:

- ***private ip address*** - in case I am on home LAN
- ***public ip address*** - in
  case I am not on home LAN

To be honest, I know this is a bit "ridiculous" request, but maybe there is some "workaround" for it.

Note: I use Ubuntu on all my servers and PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the resolution for the "problem" and it is very simple.
I followed these steps:

1. installed dnsmasq on my home server so it will become a very simple dns server
2. in my home server I added an entry with the private ip address of my home server into /etc/hosts with domain name "mytunneledowncloud.com"
3. configured my home server's DHCP daemon to assign home server's private IP as a DNS server to the clients

Now it works perfectly. My home server now acts as dhcp/dns/web server and it assigns its own private ip as a dns server to the connected LAN clients. Then clients send the requests for the DNS resolution to my home server. My home server's dnsmasq looks into its /etc/hosts whether there is an entry for the requested domain name and if there is a match, provide the IP from there and if there is no match, then it uses the "internet's" DNS servers to resolve it.